# Lag is causing collision to be late

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a jump pad that when it triggers the player and his velocity.y is less than 0(So, it activates only if the player is falling) the problem is that sometimes it does not work probably because of the lag so the player touches the ground in the following frame.How can I fix this?here is my code for triggering the pad.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D others)
{
    if(others.gameObject.name== "JumpPad"){
        Debug.Log(rb.velocity.y);
    }
    if (others.gameObject.name == "JumpPad" && rb.velocity.y<0)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, PadJumpingPower);
    }
}
```

and this is my character control script

```
if (IsGrounded())
        {
            Jump = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Jump = true;
        }
        animator.SetFloat("speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontal));
        animator.SetBool("Jumping", Jump);
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);
            Jump = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
        }

        Flip();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        if (isFacingRight && horizontal < 0f || !isFacingRight && horizontal > 0f)
        {
            isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
            Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
            localScale.x *= -1f;
            transform.localScale = localScale;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: You could change the collision detection mode of the RigidBody. Here is a [useful link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6h5FoPi3SY0).

Comment: Thanks!That helped a lot!But, It worked when I turned the collision mode to disecrete which I did not really understand why.Can you explain it to me?

Comment: What was your previous collision detection mode.